# Angular Role Based Menu And Page Routing

Tags: angular, menu, roles

I have 3 roles. Admin, Customer, and Employee. For example, when someone with username: aa@hotmail.com and password: 123 roles:[admin,customer] logs into my site, he should see (Home,Customers and business) pages in the menu. When another user with the customer role logs in, they should see (Home,Customers) pages. To summarize, how can I do role-based menu management? Can you give an example or help?

[image]

Comment: Add strict checking of roles into function when routing to another component. And use `*ng-If` to show/hide menu based on role.

Comment: As the previous post mentions, you'd be using some sort of `AuthService` to set the user's current role/s. Then, by using getters, you check if the current user has this or that role and if so, you show them the submenu (ie. using `ngIf`). Additionally, you'd be using guards (see https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) to further check if one particular component can be navigated to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily check if the current user has a certain role in his `roles` variable by using `includes` (assuming the `roles` variable is an array). Then using `*ngIf` on your template you can enable or not the pages on your menu.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nnbspx) is a stackblitz with a little example.

Moreover, be sure to use [`canActivate` interface](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) on your routes to avoid any possibility to go to any admin page without admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help :) I proceeded the project a little further and made it as follows. but " if (this.currentUser.roles.includes(RoleEnum.Customer) " works but brings the menu without going to other else ifs. Only Customer menu comes up. Custumer +User menu should come up.

"roles": [
"Customer",
"User"
]

```
@Component({
      selector: 'ngx-pages',
      styleUrls: ['pages.component.scss'],
      template: `
      <ngx-one-column-layout>
        <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </ngx-one-column-layout>
    
  `,
})
export class PagesComponent {


  //menu;

  currentUser: KullaniciKariyer;
  menu = [];
  
  appPages: Array<{title, icon, link,children}>;

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private menuService: MenuService,
    private userService: UserService) {

    this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(data => {
      this.currentUser = data;
    });


    debugger

    if (this.currentUser.roles.includes(RoleEnum.Customer)) {
      this.menu.push(MENU_ITEMS);
      //this.menu=MENU_ITEMS;
      
    }

    else if (this.currentUser.roles.includes(RoleEnum.User)) {
     this.menu.push(MENU_ITEMS_2);
      //this.menu = MENU_ITEMS_2;
    
    }
  }




export const MENU_ITEMS: NbMenuItem[] = [
  {
    title: 'qqqq', icon: 'home-outline', link: 'qLink', children: null
  },

  
];


export const MENU_ITEMS_2: NbMenuItem[] = [

  {
    title: 'aaa', icon: 'person-add-outline', link: 'aLink', children: null
  },
  {
    title: 'xxx', icon: 'list-outline', link: 'xLink', children: null
  },
  {
    title: 'yyy', icon: 'list-outline', link: 'yLink', children: null
  },
  {
    title: 'zzz', icon: 'file-text-outline', link: 'zLink', children: null
  },
  
 
];
```

Comment: If the question you asked for on the original post is answered, you should create a new post for this new issue. And I am sorry but I don't really understand what you want to say, please make another post and clarify your issue a little bit.